# Logging logs not showing up on Vercel only print (Python)

Tags: python, vercel, python-logging

I have a Python app deployed on Vercel. Print statements do show up in the runtime logs, but not logging logs. Any ideas what I could check or change?

```
import logging

...

@app.get("/ping")
async def ping():
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
    logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
    logger.info("from logger")
    print("from print")
    return {"message": "OK"}
```